# SQL query, needs to be cte or set based

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL query that uses a cursor and want to change it to be faster and also try to improve my understanding of newer SQL techniques. I am using SQL Server 2008

Pasting it here as SQLFiddle seems to be flaky right now.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE Person(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
    [Gx] [int] NULL,
    [Gy] [int] NULL)

CREATE TABLE Location(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
    [Gx] [int] NULL,
    [Gy] [int] NULL)

CREATE TABLE PersonLocation(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [PersonId] [int] NULL,
    [LocationId] [int] NULL)


INSERT INTO Person
(Name, Gx, Gy)
VALUES
('Alice',27287, 09641)

INSERT INTO Person
(Name, Gx, Gy)
VALUES
('Bob',54433, 26101)


INSERT INTO Location
(Name, Gx, Gy)
VALUES
('London',53007, 18027)

INSERT INTO Location
(Name, Gx, Gy)
VALUES
('Oxford',45142, 20563)


INSERT INTO PersonLocation
(PersonId, LocationId) 
VALUES
(2,2)

DECLARE @Table TABLE (PersonId int, SetLocation bit, Distance float)
DECLARE @PersonId int, @Gx int = 0, @Gy int = 0
DECLARE Curs CURSOR FOR SELECT Id, Gx, Gy FROM PERSON
OPEN Curs
FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @PersonId, @Gx, @Gy
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
INSERT @Table (PersonId, SetLocation, Distance) 
SELECT 
    @PersonId, 

    CASE WHEN PL.ID > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    ISNULL(SQRT(((L.Gx - @Gx) / 10) * (L.Gx - @Gx) / 10 + ((L.Gy - @Gy) / 10) * (L.Gy - @Gy) / 10) / 10, 0) 
FROM 
    Location L  
        LEFT JOIN PersonLocation PL ON L.ID = PL.LocationId AND PL.PersonId = @PersonId             
WHERE    
    ISNULL(SQRT(((L.Gx - @Gx) / 10) * (L.Gx - @Gx) / 10 + ((L.Gy - @Gy) / 10) * (L.Gy - @Gy) / 10) / 10, 0) < 250

FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @PersonId, @Gx, @Gy
END
CLOSE Curs
DEALLOCATE Curs
DROP TABLE Person
DROP TABLE Location
DROP TABLE PersonLocation

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to give the same result. [Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81778/14)

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
    P.Id AS PersonId,
    CASE WHEN PL.ID > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SetLocation,
    ISNULL(SQRT(((L.Gx - P.Gx) / 10) * (L.Gx - P.Gx) / 10 + ((L.Gy - P.Gy) / 10) * (L.Gy - P.Gy) / 10) / 10, 0) AS Distance
  FROM 
    Person P
    CROSS JOIN Location L  
    LEFT JOIN PersonLocation PL 
        ON p.ID = PL.PersonID  AND 
        L.ID = PL.LocationId
)
SELECT PersonId, SetLocation, Distance
  FROM cte
  WHERE Distance < 250;
```

Basically, the cte is used to `project` derived columns from the joins you are doing in the cursor, and the projected columns can then be used in filters, further joins etc. The cursor has the effect of a cross join between Person and Location, with at least one row per person, and potentially more if there are multiple rows in `PersonLocation`.

Comment: Thanks, I've never used cross joins before, it looks like the cross join is removing the cursor and I could use a TVP instead of a cte as well, is that correct?

Comment: Cross join just 'multiplies' all permutations of the LHS table with the RHS table (i.e. it isn't really a `join` at all). TVP can be used to replace one of the tables (e.g. you could provide a table of `@Person` as a TVP to work on). But the value of the CTE is to project derived columns into something which can be re-used in the query below, notably the `Distance` column need not be computed twice.

Comment: thanks again, I've mostly got it but need to practice on cte's a bit.